# How to change the default message structure GoLand uses when generating an automated test

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

I absolutely adore the generate test feature of GoLand.

I would just like to make a really minor adjustment to the error messages that it displays using the gotest framework.

I would really just want to change that string in the `t.Errorf()` line, how can I do this in the configuration?

[image: t.Errorf]

I'd really like to add the args in the parenthesis in the function also I would like to put the want to be on a new line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit *Test for function* template is not available in GoLand at the moment.

Please see and follow [GO-10290](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-10290).

Comment: that's a shame it's almost perfect